I'm planning to update BIOS but I'm nervous because since the BIOS settings is resetting for some reason, will it brick my motherboard if I update it?
I'm planning to update BIOS but I'm nervous because since the BIOS settings is resetting for some reason even though with a new CMOS battery, will it brick my motherboard if I update it? The motherboard is ASUS PRIME A320m K.
My PC is working fine, I can play, do work for like 5-7hrs but I have problems with only the boot process.
Two days ago my PC took too long time to boot, it shows the ASUS logo then the American Megatrends, saying about RAID mode, then I need to go to BIOS to set the time.

In this part, the date is fine and correct (Dec 06, 2024) but the time is delayed. For example when I shut down my PC at 2:00pm, then I opened it at 6:00pm, it will took too long to boot > Monitor goes on > ASUS logo > American Megatrends > then BIOS.
Then the time in BIOS is still 2:00pm (it didn't sync with the current time) but the date is still correct. Then the BIOS setting is set to default (I always disable fast boot) and also I already bought a new CMOS battery today, checked the problem and the problem still persists

This is the 2nd picture that I took was during 6:00pm.

SATA config is always set to AHCI as default so that means I never touched this setting before (since it was telling me about RAID mode).

This happened 2 days ago and also, last 4 months I dealt with some mice pee, cleaned it with electronic contact cleaner and during those 4 months, I didn't experience any hangs, freezes or any performance issue while using the PC but supposedly the hangs should happen during that time.

This problem just suddenly popped out last 2 days, didn't touch the BIOS after those 4 months.



no it's still the same time settings before this problem happened. even with the new CMOS, the BIOS clock pauses after shut down like what I said, I shutdown at 2pm, then open at 6pm, the whole process then in BIOS, the clock is still set to 2pm (the time i shut down my computer)

You have replaced the CMOS battery?

yes, already did yesterday but problem still persists. my only option right now is BIOS update but I'm nervous that it might go brick because the BIOS setting is resetting and the time will pause. Supposedly it will say 00:00 but yeah... Also If i restart my PC, it wont boot but IT WILL boot if I open the PC again (shut down and boot)

what do you think sir? should I go update it?

It’s very unlikely updating the firmware will resolve your problem

yeah i think so, the last thing that I'll do is jump CMOS, and if that fails, maybe reinstall? i dont know hope my motherboard doesn't have a problem despite i can use it for like 6-7hrs with no problems

Your motherboard DOES have a problem. Time resetting even with a known-good CMOS battery means a mainboard problem. Reinstalling the OS won't change anything.


“I'm planning to update BIOS but I'm nervous because since the BIOS settings is resetting for some reason even though with a new CMOS battery, will it brick my motherboard if I update it? The motherboard is ASUS PRIME A320m K.”

Just go ahead and upgrade the BIOS for the motherboard. I doubt it will brick anything.
